# How to open a file of emails, dynamically create folders & files using 1st 2 letters then append file with matching emails?

Tags: perl, file

That was a long question and I could not get it all in. But, I am trying to do something without MySQL here and use  files. Not the preferred method but, I need to figure it out.

1 -I want to open a file of emails that are in a single column.

```
email1@email.com
evail2@email.com
etail3@email.com
```

Could be 100k lines!

2- I then want to strip the first two characters of the email and create folders.
 ("e/em" "e/ev" or "e/et" per example *1(naturally if !exists))

3- Create a txt file named the two letters *1(if !exists). (path example = e/em/em.txt  e/ev/ev.txt and e/et/et.txt)

4- Append those files with UNIQUE emails that start with the said first two letters.
(so, e/em/em.txt would contain email1@email.com, e/ev/ev.txt would contain evail2@email.com etc. )

I know it is nuts. But that's what I need to do. (I am so spoiled by MySQL).

My attempt to do this was so miserable and time consuming... I just had to come here for guidance.

I am happy to install a file handling module if it would help.

*1 If it is beneficial to avoid directory and file checks every time, I would like to run a script that created all the possible folders and populate them with each folders empty files ahead of time. Creating 26 folders (a-z) each containing the 26 possible combinations (/aa /ab /ac) all containing appropriate two letter blank file created.

I need some lessons on how to do all this. Although silly, I still need to know how.

Addition:

The directories and filenames can in fact start with - or _

Still needs tweaking but thanks for the help:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use CGI ':standard';
print CGI::header();
use File::Basename;
use File::Path qw/make_path/;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser);
my $path='/home/xxxx/public_html/some/directory';
my $file='1.txt';
my %EmailAddresses;
  open my $IN, '<', $path.'/'.$file or die $!;
   while (<$IN>) {
   chomp;                
   $_=~ s/\s//g;
   undef $EmailAddresses{$_};
  }
for my $EmailAddress(keys %EmailAddresses) {
 ## need to sanitize substr here for use below
  my $filename= join '/', substr($EmailAddress,0,1), substr($EmailAddress,0,2), substr($EmailAddress,0,2) . '.txt';
  $filename = $path.'/'.$filename;
  my $dir = dirname($filename);
   make_path($dir) unless -d "$dir";
     open (OUT, '>>', $filename) || die $!;
     #need to check for dupes and remove other possible issues!
     print OUT $EmailAddress, "\n";
     close OUT;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry not beautified, I am in a rush but, thought I would share the progress thanks to choroba.

Comment: It would be clearer, both in your question and in your code, to refer to "addresses" rather than "emails". The phrase "an email" usually refers to an e-mail *message*, not an address.

Comment: Sorry, bunch of other mistakes and bad practice in code too but, I will strive to do better. I am learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a hash to get the unique e-mails. You have a lot of redundant steps in your structure, though - I would remove the second level directory, its name is the same as the filename, anyway.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %emails;
open my $IN, '<', '1.txt' or die $!;
while (<$IN>) {
    chomp;
    undef $emails{$_};
}

for my $email (keys %emails) {
    open my $OUT, '>>', join '/', substr($email,0,1), substr($email,0,2),
        substr($email,0,2) . '.txt' or die $!;
    print {$OUT} $email, "\n";
}
```

First grouping the emails in a hash and then printing file by file is faster:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %emails;
open my $IN, '<', '1.txt' or die $!;
while (<$IN>) {
    chomp;
    undef $emails{substr($_, 0, 1)}{substr($_, 0, 2)}{$_};
}

for my $one (keys %emails) {
    for my $two (keys %{ $emails{$one} }) {
        open my $OUT, '>', join '/', $one, $two, $two . '.txt' or die $!;
        print {$OUT} "$_\n" for keys %{ $emails{$one}{$two} };
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying second example but, keep getting No such file or directory at line 14 `open my $OUT,. `

Comment: you should create the subdirectories first; `open` won't do that for you ;)

Comment: Ahh, I even added absolute path! I don't know why I did not see that! EMBARRASSED. Your answer is great but, I need it to `mkdir` first. Now, I think a variation of your code will do just that but, I need to figure out how to go through a-z 0-9 and -_. arrays to do just that BUT, directory named `.` must be avoided. .0 .1 .a are okay.

Comment: cant edit comment anymore. Forget about any folders or files starting with  `.`. there must be a catch folder all for all that don't fall into normal filenames.

Comment: All done! I just used in the last part! ` use File::Basename;
 use File::Path qw/make_path/;

 my $file = "/home/bob/test/foo.txt";
 my $dir = dirname($file);
 make_path($dir);
 open my $fh, '>', $file or die "Ouch: $!\n"; # now go do stuff w/file

`